# macOS Big Sur - Change desktop wallpaper image (currently forced black)

Tags: macos, desktop-customization, macos-bigsur

I'm an admin on my macbook - And there's also an admin account that I don't have access to.

I'd like to change my wallpaper image from a flat black image which I think is being forced on my by some corporate policy on the other admin account.

Is there some sort of command via the terminal, or a roundabout way of updating it not through the conventional method of going through system preferences?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this is set by an MDM policy it won't matter how you try to change it, policy will override you. Ask your IT department.

Comment: I agree that it's probably unlikely that you can override a corporate policy, but sometimes they lock one method (like System Preferences) without considering other ways to accomplish the same goal.  2 questions:  (1) Can you share what it looks like when you try to change your wallpaper in System Prefs?  (2) What have you learned by Googling for command-line ways to change wallpaper on a Mac?  I found several great suggestions without trying very hard, including one which might work around restrictions, given how low-level it works: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40644/

Answer (score 0):

I had a forced black "Wallpaper" once I tried updating it via Terminal. I ran a scrpit that utilized respective sqlite db and tried to update it with some path to desired wallpaper. Once Dock got killed, it was completely gone and background was forced black.

Also changing wallpaper from system preferences panel wasn´t possible anymore. Mission Control and active spaces gone aswell and not responsive anymore.

However, I deleted that db at ~/Libary/Application\ Support/Dock and restarted my Mac. This got me back Dock and respective functionality. I.e. changing wallpaper using system preferences.

I still wonder how to change it using Terminal. Used to be fine with some osascript, anyway, yet nothing works form me in Big Sur :/